# silverlight tooltip BusyIndicator shadow effect on Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, busyindicator

I have a strange behavior in Silverlight 5 with the BusyIndicator from Silverlight Toolkit Apr 2010. I get a strange shadow effect on Silverlight 5, but in Silverlight 4 there is no shadow.

Did anyone encounter this strange behavior? Is there some compatibility issue between Silverlight Toolkit Apr 2010 and Silverlight 5?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Silverlight 5 you should upgrade to the December 2011 release of Silverlight 5 Toolkit. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435